# Pixelation shader explanation?

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, post-processing

I was looking for a pixelation shader for my postprocessing and came across this [shader snippet](http://coding-experiments.blogspot.ca/2010/06/pixelation.html) - Works pretty well! - Not a whole lot of explanations on how it works except for "Pixelation is process when pixel at [x, y] is duplicated into [x + dx, y + dy] rectangle"

I re-wrote/formatted the shader a bit:

```
out vec4 FinalColor;
in vec2 FragUV;
uniform sampler2D Texture;

void main()
{
        float Pixels = 512.0;
        float dx = 15.0 * (1.0 / Pixels);
        float dy = 10.0 * (1.0 / Pixels);
        vec2 Coord = vec2(dx * floor(FragUV.x / dx),
                          dy * floor(FragUV.y / dy));
        FinalColor = texture(Texture, Coord);
}
```

My understanding: Messing with the 'Pixels' I found that the higher this number the more pixels there on the screen/the smaller the size pixels get thus a less pixelated effect. Then he's calculating some x and y offset values based on that number and using those offsets to get new texture coordinates to sample from.

My question: I have no idea how that's actually happening. I mean how does all that achieve "duplicating a pixel at [x, y] is into [x + dx, y + dy] rectangle"? What does 15 and 10 represent? (how much to offset on x and y?) - What happens when we actually multiply dx/dy with the result of the floor function and divide the texture coordinate by them? and why 'floor' in particular?

Any help or explanation is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As a side note, a more efficient way of achieving such effect would be to just render the scene to a texture at a very low resolution and then blit that texture to screen with point/nearest filtering. Perhaps also a more intuitive approach.

Comment: Currently I'm rendering the scene to a texture, and then applying misc postprocessing effects on it (blur, edge detection etc) and so that's where I'm doing the pixelation as well - on the rendered texture. And then finally I render a fullscreen quad sampling from that texture.

Comment: Yes, I supposes so. What I meant was that by rendering to a small texture and allowing the GPU to upscale it you'd probably save a lot on pixel shader/fillrate.

Comment: So do you mean when I create my render texture (via glTexImage2d) I create it with a much lower resolution than the actual screen? and then render that texture as usual to the fullscreen quad, correct?

Comment: Yes. Then use a GL_NEAREST filter when sampling the texture. If you only care about pixelated looks, that's probably the fastest alternative. The one advantage of this shader you have is finer control over the size and count of "pixels" (tiles actually), but if you don't need that, there's the low-res rendering alternative...

Comment: I'm relatively new to OpenGL so excuse me if this sounds basic, but if I change the width and height in glTexImage2D to something small all the difference it makes is that now it draws only a portion of my scene instead of the entire screen.

Comment: You have to also adjust your projection matrix and call [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml) with the proper render size.

Comment: Oh that worked perfectly thanks! I didn't need to adjust my projection matrix because I was using an orthographic projection for a 2D game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a pixelation shader, it seems. What it does is, it divides the screen into tiny rectangles, the side of each rectangle is determined by the values dx and dy. The smaller the value of `pixels`, the more pixelated the screen is, as that increases the size of `dx` and `dy` and thus the size of the rectangles. The shader, after deciding the dimensions of the rectangle, samples the color from the lower left corner of each rectangle, and fills that whole rectangle with that color. The result is a more pixelated scene.